# struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 48000 bytes

Tags: python, struct

This is the error I am getting
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 48000 bytes
Is there anyway I can fix this without having to change the way I am trying to plot this?

```
import wave
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

infile = "trumpet.wav"
wav_file = wave.open(infile, "r")
nchannels = wav_file.getnchannels()
nframes = wav_file.getnframes()
sampwidth = wav_file.getsampwidth()
data = wav_file.readframes(nframes)
wav_file.close()
dtype_map = {1: np.int8, 2: np.int16, 3: "special", 4: np.int32}
if sampwidth not in dtype_map:
    raise ValueError("sampwidth %d unknown" % sampwidth)
if sampwidth == 3:
    xs = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.int8).astype(np.int32)
    ys = (xs[2::3] * 256 + xs[1::3]) * 256 + xs[0::3]
else:
    ys = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=dtype_map[sampwidth])
# if it's in stereo, just pull out the first channel
if nchannels == 2:
    ys = ys[::2]

#plot full signal
num_samples = 48000
data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), data)
data = np.array(data)
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(data[:300])
plt.title('Entire signal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I figured it out. I needed to have my num_samples be half of the length of the data.

```
frame_rate = 48000.0
infile = "trumpet.wav"
num_samples = 770246
wav_file = wave.open(infile, 'r')
data = wav_file.readframes(num_samples)
wav_file.close()
data = struct.unpack('{n}h'.format(n=num_samples), data)
data = np.array(data)
data = np.array(data)
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(data[:100000])
plt.title('Entire signal')
plt.show()
```